# Controller pages inaccessible in new RoR project...why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I set up a new RoR project on MAC OS Leopard, created a repository, svn added the whole Rails project, committed, checked out at my site, set up a vhost (see below), and I cannot get to a new controller page I created (/mycontroller/index). I CAN get to the "Welcome Aboard" page. I have another Ruby install (Redmine project management software) running with Apache.

I get this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /developer was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.3 with Suhosin-Patch mod_scgi/1.12 Server at colorubooks.chadjohnson.ath.cx Port 8080
```

Here is my vhost setting:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.mydomain.ath.cx
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite.mydomain.ath.cx/public
    RailsEnv development

    <Directory "/srv/www/mysite.mydomain.ath.cx/public">
        Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you create an .htaccess file enabling dispatch.fcgi? Checked file permissions? Checked your apache log files?

Comment: Okay! I copied the dispatch.fcgi file from Redmine, and I get 
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

"We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."

So, is there a standard way to install/enable the dispatch.fcgi stuff? Can you pass me a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:
In DocumentRoot you missed a /

change:

```
DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite.mydomain.ath.cxpublic
```

to:

```
DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite.mydomain.ath.cx/public
```

then you should be able to see static files in the /public directory (like the welcome aboard page)

Now I have a question for you... I presume that you want to use apache to deploy... Have you already installed and setup passenger (mod_rack) apache module?

Link to easy passenger install guide: http://modrails.com/install.html

enjoy!

Comment: Whoops...I edited that quickly before boarding a plane, and the slash is in fact there. I'll muck with the other stuff.

Comment: Okay, installed passenger, and I still get We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly. (500 error). What do I need to do? I get nothing in my /log files.

Comment: Nevermind, figured out the database.yml file was pointing to an invalid mysql.sock file. Fixed! Thanks!